# Cannot define PRIMARY KEY constraint on nullable column in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I finally created a table `employee` which contains a column `empid` that is a computed column and this column is primary key also.

It is a self referencing table, the column `managerid` references back to itself.

But now when I am saving the table after adding some more columns, I get an error

> *'Registration' table
>
>   Unable to create index 'PK_Registration'.
>
>   Cannot define PRIMARY KEY constraint on nullable column in table 'Registration'.
>
>   Could not create constraint. See previous errors.*

but my table working perfectly ....

I want to work in the table graphically not coding every time I make a change

I cannot do it in graphically cause of this error there are 100 tables I dont like to do it coding it is very irritating

I want to do it in graphically in SQL Server 2008 Management Studio is it possible?

This is my table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Registration](
    [empid]  AS ('Sale_'+CONVERT([varchar](50),[id],(0))) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(900000,1) NOT NULL,
    [First_Name] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [Last_Name] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [Address] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [E_Mail] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [Country] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [Mobile_No] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [Designation] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [managerID] [varchar](55) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Registration] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [empid] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Registration]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Registration_Registration] FOREIGN KEY([managerID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Registration] ([empid])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Registration] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Registration_Registration]
GO
```

Comment: Cannot really reproduce your problem, I could run your script with no problem (as you said) and then tried adding another column in SQL Management Studio (by clicking not by script) but I do not get the error you mentioned, maybe you got some more steps you did that you did not write about?

Comment: thanks for reply open table in designer in sql and edit the datatype  length  mobile number 40 to 41 and see the error

Comment: I did. I opened the table in the designer and added a new column. And I am able to query it, no errors. What specifically where your steps after executing this script of yours?

Comment: Using the desginer is a horrible idea (It drops and recreates the table which is a real performance problem when you make a change and the table has data). All database code is code and should be scripted and put into source control. If you don't like to write sql,too bad.

Answer (score 1):

You could just not use empid as the primary key.
Use id as the primary key.
using "[int] IDENTITY" as the primary key of a table is the most common way of doing primary keys anyway.
The primary key and clustered index will control the storage.
I cannot see any benefit from using empid as the primary key.
Just make empid a computed column.  For queries, SQL server will see that it is computed column and it uses just the primary key.  SQL server will then use just the primary key on its queries.